# Probability of winning at a wheel spin given increasing odds based on a coin toss

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a biased coin with sides '*spin*' and '*no spin*' with probabilities $0.4$ and $0.6$ respectively. If it lands on *spin*, I spin a wheel with a chance of winning. This chance increases after each coin toss dependent on the result.

Starting at $0$, if I toss a *spin* the probability of winning on the wheel increases by $0.02$ before the wheel is spun, whereas if I toss *no spin* it increases by $0.015$.

Is it possible to calculate the probability of winning on the wheel after $n$ coin tosses?

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: To win exactly on the $~n$-th spin, two things have to happen.  On each of the previous $~[n-1]~$ toin cosses, either the coin landed *no spin*, or it landed *spin* and the corresponding wheel spin did not win.  Then, on the $~n$-th coin toss, the coin must show *spin* and the wheel spin must succeed.  Take for example $~n=10.~$  It is tempting, but wrong, to reason that the number of the first $~9~$ coin tosses that came up *spin* is some element $~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,9\},~$ with $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{k}~$ equally likely ways that this could have occurred.  ...see next comment

Comment: The reason that this is wrong is that the $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{k}~$ ways are not equally likely.  Instead, they are dependent on to what extent the $~k~$ *spin*  coin tosses occurred earlier, rather than later, in the sequence of $~9~$ coin tosses.  Consequently, while there may be some (overall) elegant analytical method for obtaining a closed form formula for winning exactly on the $~n$-th coin toss, I am not seeing it.  For me, this leaves two (non-analytical) methods of attack.  ...see next comment

Comment: [1] For a specific value of $~n~$ (for example $~n=10~$), write a computer program to loop through each of the $~2^9~$ different ways of not winning on any of the first $~9~$ coin tosses and then winning on the $~10$-th coin toss.  [2] Write a computer program to simulate up to $~1000~$ [coin toss + wheel spin] tries, stopping on the first win, and ignoring the tries (if any) where there is no win.  Then, of these simulations, for any given $~n,~$ count how many of the tries ended after exactly $~n~$ [coin toss + wheel spin] combinations.

Comment: Clarification to # [2] in previous comment.  I intended that your computer program perform $~1000~$ simulations, and that in each simulation, you give up if there is no win after the first $~1000~$ [coin toss + wheel spin] combinations.  I also intended that in the computer program, you employ a random number generator, that will (for example) generate a random number $~x~$ where $0 < x < 1.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I'll go down the non-analytical route setting up some simulations